# Android studio has several problems regarding Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I am new in android studio and flutter and I have encountered several problems after installing them. I already went to flutter doctor and it's all checked so flutter isn't the problem. I can't start coding because of these problems:

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYlOQ.png) the sample code made by flutter itself I can't run it has several errors and
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZGru.png) I can't run any virtual device because it says that I don't have an internet connection which is not true. I cannot code if I can't run the sample dummy code.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Benazir, did you try to run the command **flutter pub get** on your project. Also I would highly suggest to use VS Code as your IDE.

Comment: I just done today that and flutter pub get and reopen android studio and there's no errors. Thanks! My problem now is the emulator. Is the emulator heavy? I only have a low spec laptop

Comment: That's Great! It is advisable to have at least 8GB of RAM on your laptop to be able run an emulator smoothly. Based on my experience android studio tends to run a little bit heavy, so I think VS Code with Emulator is the way to go.

Comment: Hi, just to confirm the project you're trying to run right now is a fresh one right? and it's generated from android studio? Can you try making a new flutter project but using vs code and try to run it on your device. So that we would be able to eliminate possible causes for the error.

Comment: That's too bad I have 4GB. I will follow your advice to install VS Code for my potato laptop. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hello I have done as you said. It runs however it took 25 mins. Is there any faster way to run an app? Just to check errors

Comment: Good to know that you were able to run the app on your phone. Usually it is the first build that takes a lot of time and the succeeding builds will be a lot shorter in duration.

Answer (score 1):

I think you haven't properly done the setup for Android Studio. Please check the [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/android-studio) where you will get steps for proper installation.
Few things which you can check:

- Flutter and Dart plugins should be installed in Android Studio
- If you want to run on an emulator, you will have to download the image for it whose answer you can find in previous answers.
- When you first open Android Studio, you should get an option to create a Flutter Application.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall android studio with stable internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

i would advise you to follow below steps to download system images to create virtual device

1. Select sdk manager
2. Download a system image by selecting show package details.You can download api32 system images which is the latest for now.
3. Once downloaded you can see the image file while created avd.

Answer (score 0):

Some errors i got and how i fixed it
(ERROR 1)      `[flutter] flutter doctor -v 'crumb'` is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Error: Unable to find git in your PATH. exit code 1
(FIX)   Go to  flutter installation folder and inside flutter/bin edit the flutter.bat file using a text editor and remove the line (20) that says

`IF EXIST "%mingit_path%" SET PATH=%PATH%;%mingit_path%`
The code should look like this on those lines

REM If available, add location of bundled mingit to PATH
SET mingit_path=%FLUTTER_ROOT%\bin\mingit\cmd

Save and Run flutter doctor and everything should work fine.

(ERROR 2)  flutter doctor takes too long
(fix) I downloaded the previous version of the sdk it worked like a charm

(ERROR 3) Android sdkmanager not found. Update to the latest Android SDK and ensure that the cmdline-tools are installed to resolve this.

(fix) Open Android Studio
Tools Menu, SDK Manager
In the window that comes up there are inner panels, choose SDK Tools panel
Tick Android SDK Command-line Tools
Choose Apply button near the bottom of the window
This worked

(ERROR 4) `The term 'flutter' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

(fix) put the correct part in the env variables like i had put  `D:\flutter`  insted of `D:\flutter\bin` that worked